# for breaks script execution in ZSH

Tags: zsh, globbing

I feel dumb. I have a ZSH script with eg two file loops, eg:

```
for f (*aaa*) {echo "$f"}
for f (*bbb*) {echo "$f"}
```

The script exits if the first `find` does not find matching files. I need the script to keep working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no match for `*aaa*` an error is reported by default. This is what causes your script to exit.

To avoid this the `NULL_GLOB` option has to be set. Then instead of reporting an error the pattern is simply removed from the argument list, if nothing matches.

There are several ways to set NULL_GLOB:

- **for the whole script** by passing the `-G` command line option to `zsh`. This can also be done on the hash-bang line:

```
$ zsh -G SCRIPT
```

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh -G
for f (*aaa*) {echo "$f"}
for f (*bbb*) {echo "$f"}
```

- **for all following lines** by setting it with setopt:

```
setopt NULL_GLOB
for f (*aaa*) {echo "$f"}
for f (*bbb*) {echo "$f"}
```

- **for a single pattern** by using the glob qualifier `N`:

```
for f (*aaa*(N)) {echo "$f"}
for f (*bbb*) {echo "$f"}
```

Comment: and I thought I know something about zsh... wow! this answer is great :)